# Directly transfer underlined phrases from pdf to org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, pdf

I'm learning emacs (on spacemacs) and focusing on orgmode.

Is there a way to transfer what you underline in a pdf (like in skim) directly as text in orgmode. In other words, when you underline a phrase in your pdf it appears directly in your opened orgmode buffer.
I tried the following things:

- org-mac-grab-link you can transfer the underlined pdf section to orgmode. Nevertheless, I would like to have something that does it directly while I'm reading and underlying my pdf.
- I've heard about org-noter. However, from what I gather is more for summarizing a pdf, since you can export the skeleton/headings to your buffer.

Any advice would be useful!

Comment: It would depend on what you can do on the pdf side of the house: it would need to be able to send some notification to emacs. As long as there is some triggering mechanism, this *can* be done (see e.g [org-protocol](https://orgmode.org/manual/Protocols.html#Protocols)).

Comment: I was thinking about something like that as well but haven't looked into it yet. I would prefer to have all underlined, highlighted text in the PDF file be put as a separate section in an org file (the notes file for that PDF). I think you can list all annotations in the PDF file if you are using `pdf-tools` and perhaps move that to an org file?!

Comment: Yes I found a similar procedure with skim. You can indeed export all your notes in the pdf: file>export>notes as text. Then I would just delete all lines containing the date of when the comment was made.

Comment: This might get you started: https://github.com/malb/emacs.d/blob/master/malb.org#pdf-viewer it extracts PDF annotations/highlighting to markdown and org.